# Multiply each column by their relative factor using prefix column name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a matrix like

```
id |v1_m1 v2_m1 v3_m1 f_m1 v1_m2 v2_m2 v3_m2 f_m2| 
1  |  0     .5    .5    4   0.1   0.3    0.6   4 |
2  |  0.3   .3    .4    8   0.2   0.4    0.4   7 |
```

What I want is to mulply each v's in m1 by the f_m1 column, and all the v's columns with the suffix "_m2" by ghe f_m2 column.

The output that I expect is something like this:

```
id |v1_m1 v2_m1 v3_m1 v1_m2 v2_m2 v3_m2 | 
1  |  0    2      2    0.4   1.2   2.4  |
2  | 2.4  2.4    3.2   1.4   2.8   2.8  |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for m in range (1,maxm):
    for i in range (1,maxv):
        df["v{}_m{}".format(i,m)] = df["v{}_m{}".format(i,m)]*df["f_m{}".format(m)]
for m in range (1,maxm):
    df.drop(columns=["f_m{}".format(m)])
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with some fancy dataframe reshaping:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(zip(*df.columns.str.split('_')))
df=df.stack()
df_mul = df.filter(like='v').mul(df.filter(like='f').squeeze(), axis=0)
df_mul = df_mul.unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
df_mul.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' for i, j in df_mul.columns]
df_mul
```

Output:

```
    v1_m1  v2_m1  v3_m1  v1_m2  v2_m2  v3_m2
id                                          
1     0.0    2.0    2.0    0.4    1.2    2.4
2     2.4    2.4    3.2    1.4    2.8    2.8
```

Details:

- Create MultiIndex column headers `split` on '_'
- Reshape dataframe `stack`ing the m# to rows, leaving four columns f and
  three v's
- Using `filter`, we can select the v columns and `mul`tiply by the f
  series created by selecting the single column and using `squeeze` to
  create a pd.Series from a single column dataframe
- `unstack` the m# level back to columns
- Flatten the MultiIndex column header back to single level using
  f-string with list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your matrix is a pandas dataframe called df, I would like to give my nomination for a list comprehension approach if you enjoy them.

```
import itertools

items = [(i[0][0],i[0][1].multiply(i[1][1]))
         for i in itertools.product(df.items(),repeat=2) 
         if (i[0][0][-2:]==i[1][0][-2:]) 
         and i[1][0][:1]=='f' 
         and i[0][0][:1]!='f']

df_mul = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({i[0]:i[1] for i in items})
```

It should be superfast on larger versions of this problem.

Explanation -

1. Creates a generator for cross-product between each column as (c1,c2) tuples
2. Keeps only the columns where last 2 alphabets are same for both c1,c2 AND c2 starts with 'f', AND c1 doesn't start with 'f' (leaving you with the columns you wanna operate on as individual tuples). Something like this - `[('v1_m1', 'f_m1'), ('v2_m1', 'f_m1'), ('v1_m2', 'f_m2')]`
3. Multiplies the columns, attaches a column name and saves them as items (similar structure to `df.items()`)
4. Turns the items into a dataframe